# Java set string as class name to run

Tags: java, class, reflection

I have a question, i have a code like below:

```
controller.start(c.class, 1);
```

but i want to set "c" from console. I can get/set it from args on main method . but how can i put it on c.class ? I mean how can i do that?

String a = "c";

```
controller.start(a.class,1);
```

Of course it doesnt work , but i hope i can tell u about my problem

On php we can use $$string to set/get string to variable, but i dont know how can we do it on Java ?

Comment: Look into `Class.forName(..)`.

Comment: its not working ,thanks for quick reply

Comment: What does _not working_ mean?

Comment: `Class c = Class.forName(siteClass);
controller.start(c, 1);`

its working , so thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis :))

Comment: Class c = Class.forName(siteClass); c.parseData(page); method on c cant runnable ? how can i call parseData method on c ?

Comment: `c` is a `Class`. The class `Class` doesn't have a `parseData` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More commonly used (and more secure) way of addressing this is using maps:

```
private static final Map<String, Class<?>> NAME_TO_CLASS = new Map<>();
static {
  NAME_TO_CLASS.put("c", c.class);
  ...
}

static void main(String[] args) {
  ...
  controller.start(NAME_TO_CLASS.get(args[0]), 1);
}
```

Of course in real life you'd want to check if argument is correct and is in the map NAME_TO_CLASS.contains(your_arg);

Comment: Class c = Class.forName(siteClass);

                c.parseData(page);

method on c cant runnable ? how can i call parseData method on c ?